# Removing a node from DiGraph in networkx while preserving child nodes and remapping their edges

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory

I would like to remove a node from a `DiGraph` in `networkx` in such a way that all child nodes are preserved and their edges are remapped (or old edges deleted + new created) to the parent of their parent node. The node will be removed based on the node attributes (such as what group it belongs to).

[image: Removal of node Group B]

For instance, I wish to programmatically remove nodes which have attribute `Group B` and remap all immediate child nodes to the original parent (in the case of multiple grandparents, I want to map to all of them).

I can think of a crude approach by iterating over the `DiGraph`, looking at its immediate successors and predecessors, creating relationships between them and then removing the node, but is there perhaps any more elegant way?

```py
for node in DiG.nodes(data=True):
  if node[1].get('node_group') == "Group B":
    pre = DiG.predecessors(node[0])
    suc = DiG.successors(node[0])
    for p in pre:
      for s in suc:
        DiG.add_edge(s, p) 
    DiG.remove_node(node[0])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way you could do this is by identifying the nodes you want to "remove" and contract them with their predecessors, or "parent" nodes. An [edge contraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_contraction) removes an edge from the graph and merges the two nodes that where previously joined.

So checking on the small example you've proposed:

```
from networkx.drawing.nx_agraph import graphviz_layout

edgelist = [('Group A', 'Group B'), ('Group B', 'Group C'), 
            ('Group B', 'Group D'), ('Group B', 'Group E')]
G = nx.from_edgelist(edgelist, create_using=nx.DiGraph)

plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
pos=graphviz_layout(G, prog='dot')
nx.draw(G, pos=pos,
        node_color='lightgreen', 
        node_size=1500,
        with_labels=True, 
        arrows=True)
```

[image]

Now we can find the nodes in question and contract the edges that link them to one of its predecessors with [`nx.contracted_nodes`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.minors.contracted_nodes.html):

```
parent = next(G.predecessors('Group B'))
G = nx.contracted_edge(parent, 'Group B')

plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
nx.draw(G, pos=pos,
        node_color='lightgreen', 
        node_size=1500,
        with_labels=True, 
        arrows=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Cheers! This looks like exactly what I was looking for - can you please clarify what happens when there are multiple parents, e.g. when `Group B` has parents `Group A` and `Group X`? Also - does the direction matter in the input tuple for the edge to remove?

Comment: For what I saw, once you contract a node with one of its parents, only that parent will remain, and the previous edges connecting to the child, will now connect to the parent @napoleon_borntoparty And yes, the tuple order will determine which node remains after contracting. if you contract like contract(node1, node2) -> node1 will remain